# Enable windows font cache services in windows 7 safe mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-office

I am running windows 7 in safe mode as because i am facing some issues while running it in normal mood. 
I now try to install MS office 2013 and gives me an error stating that the windows font cache service has failed to start. I tried starting it manually by going to services.msc but then it finally said that this service cannot start in safe mode.
So i was wondering if there is any way i could start this particular service.?
I was able to start windows installer service but i am having a hard time to start this one.

Comment: This feels a bit like asking the mechanic to fix your horn because your brakes failed. Why don't you tackle your actual issue, rather than flail with a supposed workaround.

Comment: I have tried tackling with my main issue. it seems i have some issues with my onboard GPU due to which it fails to start in normal mode. Also, as you may be aware that we are under lock down now and therefore cannot go to any MECHANIC as you said. so safe mode is the only option through which it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Safe boot services are loaded from this registry Key, so adding a key under "Minimal" for font cache services might fix your problem. I'm just not sure what the name they key should be.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal\ [FontCache]

if you want is in safe mode with network services then add to this key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Network\ [FontCache]

Comment: Thanks you for the comment. i will surely try this out. had done similar thing to enable audio.. it was easy then to find the key. but i have no clue on how to get the key name for this. will look into it and update if anything works. thanks again